# How to change font and size of subtitles in libvlc sharp 3.4.0?

Tags: libvlc, subtitle, libvlcsharp

Seems i'm not getting the right way to code this.
I can do almost everything done to my media player be functional except for this.

Comment: You should provide more details, like source code, error messages, screenshots, documentation links, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky, and not exposed by the LibVLC public API, which is why you can't find a C# function for this. But there is a way.

First, read how to use [LibVLC options](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/3.x/docs/libvlc_documentation.md#libvlc-options)

Then find the one you want from the [Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help).

These look like what you're looking for

```
--freetype-rel-fontsize=<int> Size

--freetype-bold

--freetype-color=<int> color
```

Use it like this

```
var libvlc = new LibVLC("--freetype-bold", "--freetype-rel-fontsize=10", "--freetype-color=65280");
```

And you would get green, bold, extra large subtitles.

For looking up usage and parameter info, you can also check out how the VLC apps use it. Here is [VLC for Android](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/blob/master/vlc-android%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fvideolan%2Fvlc%2Futil%2FVLCOptions.kt) libvlc options usage.

Comment: Mark the answer as validated if it answered your question please. And my name's not Flavio :D

Comment: It's a good solution to set options before creating a media instance and play media, but what should I do if I want to change the options while a video is playing. for example, I need a solution to change the font while the user is watching the video. I try to use `_mediaPlayer.Media.AddOption(":freetype-rel-fontsize=10")` but It doesn't work after I create media instance and play video.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with LibVLC